# Missing country in SELECT in SELECT Tutorial 'Some countries have populations' question

Tags: sql, select

The '[Some countries have populations more than three times that of any of their neighbors (in the same continent) challenge](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial)'
in SQL Zoo gives a 'correct answer' to the code below but shouldn't Nigeria which has more than three times Ghana's population be one of the answers?

This code give a 'correct' solution.

```
SELECT name, continent
FROM world x
WHERE population > all (SELECT population*3 
                        FROM world y
                        WHERE y.continent = x.continent AND y.name != x.name
                       )
```

[image: Nigeria and Ghana population from SQL Zoo]

Comment: What is your source data and expected result?

Comment: That's nice.  But Nigeria is not three times larger than Egypt, which is also in Africa.

Comment: Hi Jim, I am using a sandbox in Sqlzoo....I don't know where the data comes from. I expected to the see default answers (Russia, Australia, Brazil) with Nigeria added.

Comment: how do you know that's the correct answer?